# md-autocomplete is not showing text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using `md-autocomplete` for autocompletion, however for some reason the dropdown is not including the text that I want it to include. Here is a simplified demo of the issue:

```
<md-autocomplete flex
        md-search-text="searchText"
        md-input-name="p"
        md-items="item in search(searchText)"
        md-item-text="item.display"
        md-floating-label="Name"
        md-delay="100"
>
</md-autocomplete>
```

```js
$scope.search = function(){
    return $q.resolve([{
        value: 1,
        display: "one"
    }, {
        value: 2,
        display: "two"
    }, {
        value: 3,
        display: "three"
    }]);
};
```

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/f51f3rf4/) for a demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't included `md-item-template` in your `md-autocomplete`. Your `md-autocomplete` should look something like this:

```
<md-autocomplete flex
            md-search-text="searchText"
            md-input-name="p"
            md-items="item in search(searchText)"
            md-item-text="item.display"
            md-floating-label="Name"
            md-delay="100"
    >
    <md-item-template>
        <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/divyanshu013/s7syLobs/1/) is a working fork of your code.

Comment: Hi @Divyanshu I have been stuck here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768501/unable-to-get-the-value-from-an-array-of-object-in-md-autocomplete

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or codepen for your code? I can take a look

Comment: The problem is I am getting the value in console but it's not coming up in `md-autocomplete` fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kb5kubb6/1/

Comment: Seems like you found the solution. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
       <md-autocomplete flex
        md-search-text="searchText"
        md-items="item in search(searchText)"
        md-item-text="item.display"
        md-floating-label="Name"
        md-delay="100">
    <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i"> 
{{item.display}}</span>
<md-not-found>
Searchtext is invalid
</md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

AngularJs:

```
$scope.search = function(parum){
 var result = [{
    value: 1,
    display: "one"
}, {
    value: 2,
    display: "two"
}, {
    value: 3,
    display: "three"
}];
this.result = param ? this.result.filter(function(item) {
return (item.display.toUpperCase().indexOf(param.toUpperCase()) > -1);}) : 
this.result
return this.result
};
```

This the perfect way of using md-autocomplete and I prefer to use angular inside input tag as md-autocomplete contain many glitches and bugs.