# Unable to get the value from an array of object in md-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, autocomplete

I have an array of objects, and Now I am trying to select the data. Enclosed file is a snapshot of the object I am getting in console.
[image]

I want to get the emailid even if user search by the empid or empname or emailid from the object in autocomplete.
But I am unable to retrieve this one when I start typing in `md-autocomplete` my screen blinks and never gave me list of filter items. 
**Updated** code :

```
<md-autocomplete flex required
                                md-search-text="searchText"
                                md-input-name="autocomplete"
                                md-search-text-change="searchTextChange(searchText)"
                                md-items="item in search(searchText)"
                                md-item-text="item"
                                md-floating-label="Reporting Manager">
                                    <md-item-template>
                                        <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.empname}}</span>
                                    </md-item-template>
                                </md-autocomplete>
```

And this is my javascript `search()` function

```
$scope.search = function(text){
    var deferred = $q.defer()
    var result = []
    var resolve = function(reportingManager){
      //console.log(reportingManager)
      angular.forEach(reportingManager,function(val){
        //console.log(val)
        angular.forEach(val,function(value){
          //console.log(value)
          if(value.empid.toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase())
            || value.empname.toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase())){
            result.push(value.empname)
            //console.log(result)
          }
        })
      })
      deferred.resolve(result)
    }
    if(text){
      resolve(reportingManager? reportingManager: [])
    }else{
      resolve([]);
    }
    return deferred.promise
  }
```

reportingManager is an array of arrays which has the objects which i have included in the snapshot.
Any help on this one would be highly appreciable 
Regards

Comment: It seems that `val` is an `Object`, if that is the case, there is no `val.indexOf` function.

Comment: @Titus I am trying to look into each object in an array

Comment: You'll have to use a condition like: `val.empid.toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) != -1 || val.emailid.toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) != -1`

Comment: @Titus I tried but still same problem

Comment: Seems like `angular.forEach()` is not executing while debugging

Comment: @Titus Do I also need to bind the promise to html in `md-autocomplete` ?

Comment: You don't need to use a promise, you can just return `return resolve(text ? ($scope.current.reportingManager || []) : [])`

Comment: @Titus I have already tried this one giving an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: @Titus hi any update on this one. I am still unable to resolve the issue

Comment: `querySearch` is not getting executed while typing. `console.log(result)` is supposed to console output but while debugging it says  undefined

Comment: @Lokesh "reportingManager is the array of objects" According to the console, `reportingManager` is an array of arrays.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 OOPS!! yea and in that arrays I have value in objects. How can I get the emailid even if the user search by the empid, empname or emailid ?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I have updated my code but still no result

Comment: The problem is not clear from the code that you've posted. From your description it seems that the `search` function is never executed or, at least, `then` is never called on the `deferred.promise` object. Try to use an `ES6` promise (eg: `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {.....})`).

Comment: @Titus `search()`  is getting executed I tried debugging the program and it's fine but I am unable to get the values in `md-autocomplete`

Comment: Also, try to see exactly what the problem is by using the browser's debugger to see the actual values of the variables the `search` function uses.

Comment: Also, I think it should be `md-item-text="item.empname"` instead of `md-item-text="item.display"`

Comment: @Titus I tried to debug the value it's consolling while typing but not filtering. Still no help from `md-item-text="item.empname"` I edited my question it's an array of arrays which hold values in objects. From there I am trying to get the value in `md-autocomplete`

Comment: Then take a look at what exactly are `value` and `val`. Maybe these objects have a different structure then you're assuming they have.

Comment: @Titus I tried `console.log(val)` and `console.log(value)` but it's not consoling anything and also after putting breakpoints looks like `angular.forEach()` statement is not executing

Comment: That means that the `reportingManager` array is empty or not an array at all.

Comment: @Titus I think the problem is with this line `deferred.resolve(reportingManager ? reportingManager : [])`

Comment: @Titus no reportingManager is definitely not empty it's an array of arrays which holds values in object the image which i have posted

Comment: @Titus I am getting value of reportingManager in console before this line `deferred.resolve(reportingManager ? reportingManager : [])`

Comment: It should be `resolve(reportingManager? reportingManager: [])` instead of `deferred.resolve(reportingManager? reportingManager: [])`

Comment: You should call your own `resolve` function not the `deferred` object's function.

Comment: @Titus yea now everything seems fine all the values are coming in console. But the filter is not happening in `md-autocomplete`

Comment: You should also change `{{item.display}}` to `{{item.empname}}` or some other property of `item` because I don't think it has a `display` one.

Comment: @Titus It's already `{{item.empname}}` wait let me update my code

Comment: @Titus code updated

Comment: The `result` array contains strings instead of objects (`result.push(value.empname)`) which means that you need to use `md-item-text="item"`

Comment: @Titus My apologies I have already corrected that one but still no filteration coming up in `md-autocomplete`

Comment: But the filtered value are coming up when I console em

Comment: Have you changed `{{item.empname}}` as well ?

Comment: @Titus no that is same `{{item.empname}}`

Comment: `item` is a string now so it should be just `{{item}}`

Comment: @Titus It's still the same nothing is coming up in `md-autocomplete`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161171/discussion-between-lokesh-and-titus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would like to thank @**Titus** for being there for me and walking with me to solve my problem.

The issue was not only with Javascript code it was also with CSS. Since I was trying to put the `md-autocomplete` in a modal pop up after so many trials the autocomplete suggestions were coming up but it was behind the modal. Here is the working code

```
$scope.search = function(text){
        var deferred = $q.defer()
        var result = []
        var resolve = function(reportingManager){
          //console.log(reportingManager)
          angular.forEach(reportingManager,function(val){
            //console.log(val)
            angular.forEach(val,function(value){
              //console.log(value)
              if(value.empid.toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase())
                || value.empname.toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase())){
                result.push(value.emailid)
                //console.log(result)
              }
            })
          })
          deferred.resolve(result)
        }
        if(text){
          resolve(reportingManager? reportingManager: [])
        }else{
          resolve([]);
        }
        return deferred.promise
      }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="md-virtual-repeat-container">
                                    <md-autocomplete flex required
                                    md-search-text="searchText"
                                    md-input-name="autocomplete"
                                    md-search-text-change="searchTextChange(searchText)"
                                    md-items="item in search(searchText)"
                                    md-item-text="item"
                                    md-selected-item="selectedManager"
                                    md-floating-label="Reporting Manager">
                                    <md-item-template>
                                        <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item}}</span>
                                    </md-item-template>
                                </md-autocomplete>
                                </div>
```

**Psst ****In case you are trying to get the autocomplete in a pop up don't forget to set the high value for `z-index`

And also include the `$q` in your controller